# Remove ants from honey

Tags: food, pest-control

I have this bottle of very good honey. I was not able to use more than a few teaspoonfuls in the past few days. Today when I opened the bottle I see small ants have entered the bottle and floating in the honey (and are dead). How to remove these ants and consume honey?

Comment: Well it might sound a bit gross to someone, but ants are actually rich in protein(relative to their size and weight)

Comment: @JustDoIt - And an oddly fitting username for that comment.

Comment: I've tried them once, and they taste like nothing. You're just chewing something that's completely tasteless(at least from my perspective) @DangerZone

Comment: In native parts of Australia honey-ants are a large delicatessen, although they're more honey than ants...there are many other species eaten around the world too!

Comment: @Arazio Australia honey-ants are a large delicatessen? That sounds crunchy.

Comment: Does honey get bad or not usable if it gets filled with ants?

Comment: @user19036 honey is antibacterial so should be safe for consumption

Answer (score 5):

Warm the honey to make it less viscous (you may even need to add a little water), then pour through a fine strainer or cheesecloth.

Comment: I like the approach, I just don't like how messy it will get

Comment: Heating honey make it lose some of its "medicinal" properties. AFAIK

Answer (score 4):

Slowly sink a drinking straw into the honey, aiming for an ant.  The ant should be smaller than the straw and should wind up inside of it. Plug the open end (at the top) with your thumb, and quickly lift the straw out of the honey.  You can then blow on the clean open end to eject the honey-plus-ant into the trash or sink. Repeat for each ant.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

> How to remove these ants and consume honey?

I'll answer the first part first. If there are only a few (less than a dozen or so), in the jar, you can use a long, pointy object, like a chopstick, and push the ants one by one to the edge and work them to the surface, where they can be picked out.

If your honey has so many ants in it that you cannot easily remove them all, consider giving up on that bit. In the summer you could put it outside and let bees take it back.

To consume honey, place small amount in mouth, mix with saliva, and swallow. (just kidding xD)

Answer (score 2):

Simply take a spoon and scoop them out bit by bit. They will be on the top and close to one edge since they can't negotiate very far in the goo. Rinse and dry the spoon after each scoop to clean it.

Did it yesterday to a seven pound plastic pail full of honey. There were some honey worshipers gathered at the edge of the lid where I was sloppy pouring some last time I used the container.

Put the lid on securely to avoid the problem. Rinse off the container to discourage the critters in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Removing ants from honey:  Bought a brand new bottle of honey, used it once and somehow the cap did not close well.  Next day a black layer of ants on the top.  Problem was, it was the plastic "pouring type" bottle, so very narrow at the top, while most of the ants were in the wider part of the neck.  I switched on my gas hob, held a sharp knife in the flame for a few seconds and sliced off the neck of the bottle.  All the ants were dead and right at the top. With a strong back light, I was able to remove every single ant with a spoon, not losing much honey in the process.  Poured it into a tight fitting glass jar.  No need to throw away the honey or "eat" the ants as suggested!

Comment: Hi Marlena de Villiers, Welcome to Lifehacks.SE.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

How about a honey siphon with irrigation hose?! Put some grapefruit extract around the pipe to prevent ants from migrating.

It’s a slow flow but it works.

Answer (score 0):

What I do is this : freeze honey. Remove honey and put in the middle of a bowl of water.
Scoop a teaspoon of honey in mug. Add tea and hot water.
Ants will float to the top.
I scoop out ants using spoon and discard them in the sink.
The rest is good to go.